Download images from URL and rename them with text with empty spaces taken from cell
I've been successfull using this macro for downloading pictures and renaming them with a text included in a related cell:
URLs are in column E, filenames in column F
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As LongLong, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongLong, ByVal lpfnCB As LongLong) As LongLong
    
Sub ScaricaImnmagini()
Dim strSavePath As String
Dim URL As String, ext As String
Dim buf, Ret As LongLong
Dim miorange As Range
Dim cll As Range
Set miorange = Range("e2:e10") '<--- Example

For Each cll In miorange
    URL = cll.Value
    strSavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & cll.Offset(0, 1).Value& "." & "jpg"
    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
Next cll
End Sub

The code does not work for cells with spaces or / symbols.
Here's the error. I want all files to be downloaded, renamed and saved but I can get only 2 out of 10 as other cells contain spaces or slashes.
As I need the files to be renamed exactly that way, I can't simply change the file name.

I've added a screenshot, only files with "ok" next to them could be downloaded

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. It also doesn't show the error messages you get, and we need those to understand what's wrong. Help us help you by adding all those details to your question.

I don't know why spaces would matter, but slashes are accepted as separators between directories in a path, and if that directory doesn't exist, you cannot create a file in it.
I'd replace all problematic characters (backslashes and colons come to mind), or just allow known valid ones (letters, digits, underscores) and remove everything else from the file names.
You can use a regular expression for this. Something like below. Based on How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops and untested cause I don't use Windows or Excel.
Dim filename As String
filename = cll.Offset(0, 1).Value
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]"
End With
filename = regEx.Replace(filename, "")

URL = cll.Value
strSavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & filename & "." & "jpg"
Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)

This should remove all characters that are not letters or digits or underscore from the file name.

Unfortunately, I need the names to be exactly as written in the cells. So if name in cell is "ABC 01", I want the .jpg file to be created, saved and named "ABC 01.jpg"

You can add a space to the regular expression to preserve it, but if you couldn't create files with spaces, this may still fail. It would be helpful to add the (English) error messages you got to your question.

This is very helpful in renaming the cells, but I don't want to rename them. I'd like my .jpg files to be saved exactly as per the text included in the cells. Somehow, the VBA function does not accept texts with spaces or slashes
